# Accessing webContents from within preload script in BrowserWindow

Tags: electron

I want to create a "Worker" `BrowserWindow` from within a render process. The worker process will do some long running calculations and periodically report back.

Instead of creating the worker BrowserWindow from within the main process directly, it looks like I can use the `remote` module to do so from within the renderer process:

```
import remote from 'electron'

        const workerWindow = new remote.BrowserWindow({
            show: false,
            webPreferences: {
                preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preloadWorker.js')
            }
        });

workerWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/worker.html');
```

I figured I can use the `webContents` object of the `workerWindow` to listen for updates like this:

```
workerWindow.webContents.on('worker-result', (event, msg) => console.log(msg));
```

But what I can't figure out how to do is emit events from the 'preloadWorker.js' file. I want to do something this in the `preloadWorker.js`,

```
setInterval(() =>{
    this.webContents.send('worker-result', 'hello from worker');
}, 1000);
```

Now I know I could do all of this by sending messages using `ipcMain` and `ipcRemote`, but I'm trying to save myself some work...it seems like I should be able to access the `webContents` from within the `preload.js` script somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question, and you might not need it anymore.  However, you can use `ipcRenderer.sendToHost` to communicate with the webview that your preload script is bound to.

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

setInterval(() => {
  ipcRenderer.sendToHost('worker-result', 'hello from worker');
}, 1000);
```